# Google Custom Search API C# 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0, google-search-api

I need to call Google Custom Search API in my .NET 2.0 project.
I cannot use the [Google Libraries](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/libraries) because those are written in .NET 3.5. I've tried to compile them in .NET 2.0 but there are big dependencies in LINQ and Json.NET 3.5 version of the library.

I tried to use the 2.0 version of the Json.NET library but i cannot get the JSON response to be deserialized into one of my custom object classes.
The problem is with deserialization. Can i ignore fields in deserialization? The deserialization always returns error because i cannot get the class that represents the JSON answer from Google.

Comment: Why not just upgrade your project to .NET 3.5? it's merely an extension of .NET 2.0?

Comment: Because i can't. I have component dependencies.

Comment: Why would your component dependencies break if you upgraded from 2.0 to 3.5? Have you tried it?

Comment: Most importantly, my client don't allow me to. It's a huge project that i cannot upgrade due to a particularly need.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work.
I've used this site: [Generate Class based on JSON](http://json2csharp.com/#) to get the full representation of my JSON in .Net Classes.
After that i got an error on deserialization because google is returning this value: "msvalidate.01" and it could not get represented in class for deserialization.

After i decorate with this attribute

```
[JsonProperty("msvalidate.01")]
public string msvalidate;
```

i managed to get it to work.